# Installing libraries and dependencies in Django app

Tags: python, django, dependency-management

I'm new to Django, and somewhat web development in general; I'm running a Django app on Heroku that is a very basic prototype facebook-type web application. I want to incorporate encryption, specifically a scheme from the library Charm: https://github.com/JHUISI/charm

I want to use this is my app, but I don't know how to install it other than on my own machine. According to the Charm readme, I also need to have GMP, PBC and OPENSSL dependencies installed. This is all done on my own computer, as I can successfully run the schemes locally, but I'm at a loss as to how I would get this running on my web app.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have not used heroku, but it looks like they might support providing and installing your own binaries https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries#packaging-binaries

Comment: That looks like the way to go. Appreciate your help!